# Add smiley face in c

Tags: c, ubuntu

I am trying to print  smiley face using C. My program is

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int x;
    char i=1;
    for(x=1;x<=800;x++) 
    {
        printf(" %c ", i); 
        if(x==800)
        printf("\n"); 
        if(x==800)
        break;

    }
}
```

I am using Ubuntu Terminal. It is working fine in `Windows` but not in `Ubuntu`.  Please help. Thanks in advance

Comment: You are printing the char i=1 `printf(" %c ", i);`
 that correspond to start of header (soh) which is a non-printable character (see man ascii)

Comment: Why `y=x` and `if(y==800)` ? use directly `if(x==800){ printf("\n"); break;}`

Comment: @terence hill : solution???

Comment: The solution depends on which character you want to print. You can see the printable character from that ascii man page. However, your code does not print a smile face but just a line of the same character,

Comment: Do you want to print a line of smiley face or a set of character that compose a smiley face on the terminal?

Comment: You mean it works under DOS, where the default [character codepage](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codepage_437) has white and black smileys at code points 1 and 2. Obviously, Ubuntu doesn't use DOS codepages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to output a smiley face you cannot use the ascii characters.
Again, look at that ascii man [page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/ascii.7.html) for the complete set of available characters.

However you can use the [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) encoding, if your terminal support it.
The code snippet below print a smiley face with sunglasses on my terminal:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
 char s[] = { 0xf0, 0x9f, 0x98, 0x8e, 0};

 printf("%s\n", s);
}
```

Another possibility is to use

```
printf("\u263A\n");
```

According to his [UTF-8](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/263a/index.htm) page which report the `C/C++/Java` source code